# Android Compose - How to convert Offset to IntOffset

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm doing some work creating UI pieces in compose. I am doing things with Offsets and converting between different coordinate spaces of views. All the conversions work with `Offsets`, but then when you need to actually specify a position of a view using the `offset` modifier, you must supply an `IntOffset`.

So, my question is twofold;

What "units" is `Offset` representing? Is it pixels, dp, or just "arbitrary Cartesian space"? And how do I convert an `Offset` to an `IntOffset`(i.e. pixel offset)?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

[`Offset`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui-geometry/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/geometry/Offset.kt) can represent any unit, the class itself doesn't specify that. Unit should be specified in the documentation of api that returns/receives `Offset`. For example, the [`.offset` modifier](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/7e55b4019e7d9e07eefa6037928cf44dcb3df805:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Offset.kt;l=105) documentation says: "*Offset the content by [offset] px.*". You can be pretty sure that any jetpack-compose related apis will expect `Offset` to be in pixels, as there is [`DpOffset`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/7e55b4019e7d9e07eefa6037928cf44dcb3df805:compose/ui/ui-unit/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Dp.kt;l=254) for offsets in dp.

So to convert `Offset` to `IntOffset`, just rounding the values is enough. You can use extension function [`Offset.round()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/7e55b4019e7d9e07eefa6037928cf44dcb3df805:compose/ui/ui-unit/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/IntOffset.kt;l=179) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Offset(x,y).round() for conversion from `Offset` to `IntOffset`

```
@Stable
inline fun Offset.round(): IntOffset = IntOffset(x.roundToInt(), y.roundToInt())
```

`Offset` and `IntOffset` are both used for pixel values in Jetpack Compose. Especially IntOffset is defined as

```
/**
 * A two-dimensional position using [Int] pixels for units
 */
@Immutable
@kotlin.jvm.JvmInline
value class IntOffset internal constructor(@PublishedApi internal val packedValue: Long)
```

Offset can represent An immutable 2D floating-point offset but it's generally used for representing pixel values with default Modifiers, or functions.

First one is generally used in DrawScope(Canvas) or Modifier.pointerInputScope(Gesture) while IntOffset is returned from size of Composables with Modifiers such as onSizeChanged, onPlaced or onGlobabllyPositioned and used inside Modifier.offset{IntOffset} or in Layout to place Placeables or Composables inside that Layout.

To convert from pixel value to dp you need to call pixel value/ density value or with density or inside a scope with Density. Same goes from dp to pixel conversion as well dp value is pixel value * density

```
val density = LocalDensity.current

with(density){
    100f.toDp()
    100.dp.toPx()
}

Canvas(modifier = Modifier){
    100f.toDp()
    100.dp.toPx()
}

Layout { measurables, constraints->
    val placeables = measurables.map {
        it.measure(constraints)
    }

    // This is a Density scope
    100f.toDp()
    100.dp.toPx()

    // You can place placeable in pixels in Int
    val offset = IntOffset(100,200)
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight){
        placeables.forEach {
            it.placeRelative(offset.x, offset.y)
        }
    }
}

Column {
    // This is not possible because ColumnScope does not expose density
    100.dp.toPx()
}
```